# oracle 11g File Reading inside PL/SQL proc without creating directory

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

I am working on `PL/SQL` block where I need to read from the test-file, bulk collect and pass it as a parameter to other procedure.

The challenge I am facing is I have only procedure execute access, and I will be allowed to create the procedure which I am writing. (don't have permission to create External table )

steps

```
Read file,  
bulk collect,  
call proc_2(cursor)
```

please suggest me what is the best approach.
Thanks in Advance.

Comment: From PL/SQL you can only read a file on the DB server (or at least visible to it, e.g. via an NFS mount) and via a directory object which your DBA has to create and grant you privileges on. (There is an old `utl_file_dir` method but it isn't recommended and I doubt your DBA would allow). You probably need to talk to your DBA about the best to achieve that under their rules and restrictions, and based on where the file will be sitting.

Comment: External table essentially uses SQL*Loader drivers to load from flat files. So, you may  pre-load the data from a `sqlldr` script (windows/unix) into a normal table and skip the creation of external table in the PL/SQL procedure.

Comment: Basically the restrictions placed on your assignment prevent you from being able to complete the assignment. You cannot read a file from the operating system without being given access database level to the operating system. So you need to discuss this with the person who gave you the assignment, understand why these restrictions are in place and formulate an approach to removing or ameliorating them.